# Can't remove Nvidia linux module

Tags: apt, nvidia, kernel, dpkg

I'm trying to remove a specific nvidia linux module but it doesn't work:

```
sudo dpkg --remove --force-remove-reinstreq linux-modules-nvidia-525-5.15.0-84-generic
```

which returns:

```
Reading database... 
226734 files and directories already installed.
Removing linux-modules-nvidia-525-5.15.0-84-generic (5.15.0-84.93)...   
linux-image-nvidia -5.15.0-84-generic: removing .ko files 
/bin/sh: 0: cannot open ./CLEAN: No such file dpkg: error processing package linux-modules-nvidia-525-5.15.0-84- generic (--remove): 
installed linux-modules-nvidia-525-5.15.0-84-generic package pre-removal script   
subprocess returned error exit status 2 
Errors were encountered during execution: linux-modules-nvidia- 525-5.15.0-84-generic
```

Comment: Correction by: reinstall the related driver, then immediately remove it, might that work?

Comment: That is the nVidia program, not supported by dpkg. You have to use nVidia's program to uninstall it. http://us.download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86_64/535.113.01/README/installdriver.html#OtherFeaturesOfd7638 With Ubuntu, you never should install the nVidia .run file, but install directly from Ubuntu's repository during install or with `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall` at recovery mode terminal.